# How to Generate Java Classes from WSDL and Add Custom Annotations with SOAPAction Value?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, xjc

I need to generate java classes from wsdl and add custom annotation to them with value SoapAction. This value should be taken from wsdl.
I tried to make a custom plugin. I made class extended from `com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin` class. But I don't understand, how to get values from wsdl?